# mv Command does not work when used in cases?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I'm trying to move the generated file to it's appropriate directory. When I'm not using the cases, it moves my file to the right directory just fine. However, now that I'm introducing it different parameters using cases, it's not even moving the file anymore. As stated in the comments, I'm not getting any sort of errors. I don't see issues in my logs

```
#!/bin/bash
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The statement below includes the batch path directories.


daily="/POO/fos/File_Ordering_Logs/Daily"
weekly="/POO/fos/File_Ordering_Logs/Weekly"
monthly="/POO/fos/File_Ordering_Logs/Semiannually"

spoolFilterDir="/POO/fos/spool_error_chk"

_endDate=$(date +"%m%d%Y")
_day=$(date +"%u")

#------------------------------------------------------------------------

case "$1" in
    (daily)
        directory=$daily
        _beginDate=$(date -d "1 day ago" +"%m%d%Y")
        report="$_endDate"DailyFOSReport".csv"
        ;;

    (weekly)
        directory=$weekly
        _beginDate=$(date -d "7 days ago" +"%m%d%Y")
        report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"WeeklyFOSReport".csv"
        ;;

    (monthly)
        directory=$monthly
        _beginDate=$(date -d "183 days ago" +"%m%d%Y")
        report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"SemiAnnualFOSReport".csv"
        ;;  
esac

touch "$spoolFilterDir/$report"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Error filter
#
exec_error_filter()
{
cd $spoolFilterDir

grep --include "*.csv" -e "ERROR" -e^SELECT -e^TNS -e^SP2 -e^ORA ${spoolFilterDir}/${report}
greprc=$?

if [[ $greprc -eq 0 ]] ; then 
    echo "--------------------------------"
    echo "Erroneous data spooled to .csv report. Removing report."
    echo "--------------------------------"
    rm ${spoolFilterDir}/${report}

else
    echo "FOS report successfully generated."
fi  

case "daily" in
    (daily)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $daily
        ;;
    (weekly)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $weekly
        ;;
    (monthly)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $monthly
        ;;
esac

}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#END
```

Comment: More info needed. Are you getting any error messages (if so, include *exact* message text)? What're the relevant variables, and how do they match with the variables' values? Also, what does running it with `set -x` show?

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. The file is simply not moving once I use the mv command with cases. Everything works perfectly when I'm just using the mv command for 1 of the directories.

Comment: This code above works fine so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please answer all of Gordon's questions. We need to know more info. It would really help if you could create a [mcve]. Right now we can't tell what `$1` is, for instance.

Comment: Note that we ask that you provide a [mcve] -- that's the **shortest possible** code that reproduces the specific, narrow problem your question is about. See the "Tricks for Trimming" section at http://sscce.org/ for additional guidance on how to generate a minimal reproducer from your full program.

Comment: (Moreover, sample code that requires people to have `sqlplus` installed when the question isn't *about* sqlplus is violating the "verifiable" part of those guidelines, since it prevents others from reproducing your issue and testing their solutions; likewise for code referring to directories that only exist on your machine).

Comment: I count some `100` warnings and potential errors when I paste your code into [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) try it `:)`

Comment: Another good place to start is run run `bash -x yourscript` -- you can see the arguments *actually* passed to `mv`, and work backwards from there to figure out why it isn't behaving as-intended.

Comment: Hey everyone, I updated to a more verifiable version. If anything else needs to be done, please let me know. David Rankin, thank you for that website. I'll give it a look.

Comment: David Rankin, wow! What a super useful website. For my mv commands, when it's not inside double quotations, it states I should double quote to prevent globbing. However, when I put double quotes around it, it says there's no destination?

Comment: What "it"? The quoting should be akin to `mv "$spoolFilterDir/$report" "$weekly"` -- each argument separately quoted. If you run with `bash -x`, you'll see what those actually expand to -- if one of those variables is unexpectedly empty, there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here:

```sh
case "daily" in  ### <- always hardcoding the word "daily"
   (daily)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $daily
        ;;
    (weekly)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $weekly
        ;;
    (monthly)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $monthly
        ;;
esac
```

I think you meant:

```sh
case "$1" in
    (daily)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $daily
        ;;
    (weekly)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $weekly
        ;;
    (monthly)
        mv ${spoolFilterDir}/${report} $monthly
        ;;
esac
```

The way you have written it, the code will always fall into the "daily" case no matter what.

In addition to that, your function `exec_error_filter` is not called anywhere. This may also explain why nothing is happening.

Comment: Good catch! (That said, as other folks having trouble using `mv` inside `case` statements are unlikely to find the question/answer pair applicable, the question is probable eligible for close-as-typo).

Comment: That was my mistake. I was forcing it to accept a value to see if the case is even being seen. When using $1, it doesn't seem to be falling into the cases. When I assign a variable in the first CASEs and pass that value into the CASE for the exec_error_filter() function, it works.